# Laravel pivot table additional relations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models `User` and `Group` that have a many to many relation. Their pivot table group_user looks like this:

```
user_id
group_id
role_id
```

The role_id is supposed to show what role the user has in that group.

My question is how can I create a new relation using model itself and not the id. So instead of this:

```
$group->users()->attach(User::create(), ['role_id' => Role::find(1)->id);
```

How can I do something like this:

```
$group->users()->attach(User::create(), ['role' => Role::find(1));
```

By default I get this error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'role' in 'field list'

Comment: retain `role_id`